# ASP.Net MVC Posting back formatted timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Below is part of my model:

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public TimeSpan Opening { get; set; }
```

This works fine in and diplays the required timespan as hh:mm tt. but when i post this back the model is not valid and says the value is not valid (eg: 04:00 AM). i guess it is expecting it in the same format of hh:mm:ss . is there anyway i could resolve this? should i use custom model binding, or move the display format to view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is going to be the AM portion of the time.  TimeSpan indicates an amount of time such as 2 hours or 1 day.  It isn't a specific time of day. You need to use a different format though. I'd suggest trying this without the format  as a timespan's format is very similar to what you're looking for anyways.

Comment: I do understand that TimeSpan is more of an interval. but unfortunately .Net doesn't have a time object. hence trying to use TimeSpan. is there any alternative where i could use a time picker and set a time like hh:mm tt

Comment: With your requirements you may be better of just removing the validation from the field with something similar to this.

`$("#timefield").validate({
  ignore: ".ignore"
});`